# MySQL : Group by WEEK on date field returning weird results

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a table which captures when certain events (say alien attacks) happened. Each time the aliens attack a new record is created in this table (some days can have multiple attacks and some days none)..

```
   attack_id         attack_date
   ---------         ---------
   1                 2015-10-27 
   2                 2015-10-28
   3                 2015-11-03
   4                 2015-11-06
   5                 2015-11-09
```

I want a count of how many attacks happened on a given week so I do a SQL like this..

```
 SELECT WEEK(alien_date) as attack_week, COUNT(*) as num_of_attacks 
 FROM alienAttack
 GROUP BY WEEK(alien_date)
```

But in the result set I am seeing...

```
   attack_week  num_of_attacks
    1           2
    2           1
   43           2
   44           2
```

Why did it suddenly jump from week 2 to week 43? I was expecting the next result set to be week 3.

Comment: Can you confirm that actually has data in your database from week 3 to 42? I mean do you have dates between (more or less) 01/15 and 10/15 ?

Comment: The SQL seems right. Can't see your data and can't decide whats wrong.